# What is the difference between the JAVA_HOME environment variable and the output of "java -version"

Tags: java, environment-variables, java-home

What is the JAVA_HOME environment variable actually? I'm in doubt. What is done by setting it ? And I have also another question that if we have two or more JDK s in the OS, we can set one version's path to set the $JAVA_HOME variable and another version as the running java in the machine which is shown by "java -version" command.As I think in ubuntu, java --version command gives the JRE configured (running java) version of java and JAVA_HOME variable defines which version to use for compiling java programs. Am I correct? What is actually the difference between the jdks referred by these two outputs-

```
    1. echo $JAVA_HOME 
    2. java -version
```

Answer (score 6):

Lets start with what the two commands *do*.

```
  echo $JAVA_HOME
```

This outputs the value of the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.  By convention, this environment variable is set (typically in a shell "rc" file) to the base directory of a JRE or JDK installation.  However, none of the Oracle or OpenJDK core java tools depend on this.  You set `JAVA_HOME` for the benefit of 3rd-party tools, to tell them which of possibly many JRE or JDK installations on the system to use.

So running `echo $JAVA_HOME` will *typically* give the directory for *a* JRE or JDK.  But it might be unset ... or point to missing directory.

```
  java -version
```

This runs the `java` command and tells it to output *its own* version information.  Unlike the previous, if your shell can find a (real) `java` command, the information it outputs is definitive.

But which JRE / JDK does will the `java` command come from?

Well that is determined by the shell, and how it (in general) finds commands.  For all mainstream Unix / Linux / BSD shells, this is controlled by the PATH environment variable.  The PATH variable defines a command search path; i.e. a list of directories where the shell looks for commands.

So if `PATH` is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/joeuser/bin:/usr/java/jre-x.y.z/bin` then the shell will look for `java` in each of those directories *in turn*. The first one `java` command that it finds will be the one that is executed.  You can find out which one it is by running this command.

```
  which java
```

But that is not the end of it, because if you are using an OpenJDK Java installation on a typical Linux system, the `java` command in `/usr/bin` is actually the first in a chain of symlinks that is managed by the `alternatives` command.  The actual executable is at the other end of the chain.

(The alternatives system is a way to implement a *switchable* system-wide default for a command or set of commands.  Read the manual entry for more details.  But note that Oracle Java installers (or RPMs) for Linux don't "grok" the Linux alternatives system ... one of my bugbears!)

Finally, it is common to see something like this in a shell "rc" file:

```
  export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jre              # (or jdk)
  export PATH=/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:/usr/bin:...
```

There is nothing magical about this.  The `$JAVA_HOME` is going to be expanded by the shell before it sets the environment variable.  Tthe actual `PATH` value will be:

```
  /bin:/path/to/jre/bin:/usr/bin:...
```

---

So in summary:

- `echo $JAVA_HOME` tells you the JRE or JDK that a typical 3rd-party tool will try to use by default.
- `java -version` tells you the JRE or JDK that the `java` command comes from.
- They may be different.

Comment: So if the above 2 refer to 2 java versions,(this happened in my ubuntu os) is it possible that two applications in the os will use different java versions?

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jre              # (or jdk)
export PATH=/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:/usr/bin:...            ////If 2 of these commands are set in a shell rc file, there is no posibility that echo $JAVA_HOME and java -version refer to two java versions. Am I correct???

Comment: If your shell has sourced the rc file, then you are correct.  But this is all "Linux shell 101" stuff.  Perhaps you need to find and read a good tutorial / book on using the Linux shell ...

Comment: If the above 2(echo $JAVA_HOME and java -version) refer to 2 java versions,(this happened in my ubuntu os) is it possible that two applications in the os will use different java versions? what is your idea on this?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.  Whether it actually does happen that way depends on the applications, and how they (or their respective wrapper scripts) figure out which JRE installation(s) to use.

Comment: Very useful answer, specially the information on how the shell searches for the first java in the PATH, be it $JAVA_HOME/bin (if it is in the PATH) or another one that he finds earlier. Now I understand why we usually see $JAVA_HOME/bin concatenated early in the PATH and not at the end of it.

Answer (score 2):

`JAVA_HOME` is an environment variable that contains the directory where Java is installed (if a few versions of Java are installed - this will point to the default)

`java -version` is a command that shows which version of Java is installed (and again, the one that's used by default in case a few versions are installed)

**Addition**: Thanks to Luiggi's comment: if the folder where `java` is installed is not in the `PATH` (another environment variable) - running `java -version` or any other `java` command will fail!

Comment: Note that `java -version` fails in Windows if you don't set the location of `java.exe` in `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza correct. If `java` is not in the `PATH` any java command will fail!

Comment: Also, you should configure JAVA_HOME manually. And you can make the mistake to put the wrong value for it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you configure it manually in windows ? cause in Mac it comes with the installation.

Comment: In Windows you configure all of them. Manually. And yes, it can fail horribly.

Comment: *"JAVA_HOME is an environment variable contains the directory where Java is installed"* - That is a convention only.  The Oracle Java tools (at least) do not depend on $JAVA_HOME.

Comment: @StephenC thanks! I guess that it explains why this env variable is not set by default when Java is installed on Windows ?

Comment: so what is the usage of this setting java_home variable?

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga there are applications that depend on this variable to do all sorts of things (or even just to be functional). Here is [one example](https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/article.html?id=348)

Comment: Do u mean that java.exe(to run java programs) and javac.exe (to compile java files) are found by the os using that JAVA_HOME variable at sometimes by some applications? And what if the JAVA_HOME is referring to a one java version and java -vesion shows another java version?

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga if the application uses JAVA_HOME then that's the version of Java that it'll use regardless of the output of `java -version` in command prompt. According to the comments of Stephen and Luiggi above, the OS may or may not use JAVA_HOME (it's only a convention).

Answer (score 0):

Its not related to jdk and JRE. `java -version` it is used by the java which is in /usr/bin/java. In some application is used $JDK_HOME. Both the jdks are same. Or we can define different jdk.

Comment: Do u mean that java.exe(to run java programs) and javac.exe (to compile java files) are found by the os using that JAVA_HOME variable at sometimes by some applications? And what if the JAVA_HOME is referring to a one java version and java -vesion shows another java version? What will happen then?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

will print the value of environment variable called `JAVA_HOME`. If it's not set, it will print an empty message. Usually, you set `JAVA_HOME` to the path of the latest JDK installed in your pc.

```
java -version
```

will print the version of the java executable (Java Virtual Machine) that is set in your path, if configured. Otherwise, it will throw an exception on the command line.